# What is this on my Crimson King Maple leaves that are drying up with sticky film on leaves

Tags: trees, diseases, maple

A week ago only some of the leaves on the Crimson King Maple became dried and some of the other leaves have a waxy or slimy film that is on them. The leaves are sticky looking with a film on the leaves. In the picture the leaves are drying up.

[image: crimson king maple]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: It is hard to see what's going on with the leaves from the photo you posted, because the leaves are dark and crowded together and the photo does not magnify well. I think I can see black spots on one leaf to the left but can't tell what they are,. Inspect the underside of the leaves and the trunk for anything that shouldn't be there, such as insects or scale insect - scale will look like rounded, shield shaped bumps, sometimes with white stuff round the edges.